# Drawing irregular shapes in android over on gridlines with entering measurment each of sides

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application to calculate an area with the given measurement of any irregular shape, so need to draw an any irregular shape over on gridlines also with entering measurement of each side, How can i do this in android

Comment: each time you need different shapes?

Comment: yes but freehand drawing - might be like polygon line using google map

Comment: @SanjayBhalani - hai, can I get an idea for my question